# FusionCharts 3.2.1 - bigger step/scale for large periods of time

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I'm creating a chart by calling the fusion charts constructor (`new FusionCharts()`) with the necessary properties). Everything works OK with small periods (1,2 months) ... But when I increase the period: 1,2 years the horizontal days values appear above the others.

Is there a way to increase/parametrize the scale for large periods of time?

Comment: Since the answer to this is dependent on chart type, its dimension and the data XML/JSON, I would like you edit your question to include them.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the chart automatically tries to manage the overlapping labels. However, in version 3.2.2 (named as FusionCharts XT), better automatic label management is applied. You can try updating/upgrading and check with the new version.

Besides, can you specify the chart type you are using?